# Missing Dots and Line Style in Figure Legend with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

After running the following commands:

```
Population <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B")
Group <- rep(c("Experimental", "Experimental", "Control", "Control"), 2)
wave <- rep(c("Pretest", "Posttest"), 4)
outcome <- c(-.3, -.2, -.3, .4, -.6, -.5, -.6, .6)
ci <- rep(c(.13, .14), 4)
df <- data.frame(Population, Group, wave, outcome, ci)
df$wave <- factor(df$wave,levels = c('Pretest','Posttest'))

library(ggplot2)
pd <- position_dodge(0.1)
ggplot(df, aes(x = wave, y = outcome, color = interaction(Population, Group), shape = Group, group = interaction(Population, Group))) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = outcome - ci, ymax = outcome + ci), width = .25, position = pd, size=.5) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = Group), position = pd, size=1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_point(position = pd, size = 3.5, fill = "white", stroke = 1.25, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#000000", "#606060", "#000000", "#606060")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(23, 21)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1.4, 1.6), ylim = c(-.91, .91)) +
  labs(title = "Outcomes by Population and Study Group", x = "Time", y = "Outcome\nLower scores denote fewer instances", color = "Population and Study Group")  +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black"), axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black"), panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#F0F0F0"))
```

I generate a figure that does not have dots symbols or correct line styles in the legend:

[image]

How can I:

- add the dots shown in the figure itself into the legend and
- have the legend lines reflect that some of dotted lines in the figure?

TYIA.

Comment: Further research into and fiddling with this suggests the issue is with the calls in the initial `ggplot` command itself not being modifiable by later commands--even if I first try "[clearing](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/)" those commands with, e.g., `geom_point()`

Comment: I tried to answer your question below to not send you in circles. This is more suitable for stackoverflow so you can post there the next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to create another variable that would reflect the interaction instead of creating it on the fly. If we build the plot step by step, this below gives the dots and errorbars:

```
library(ggplot2)
pd <- position_dodge(0.1)
df$grp = paste(df$Population,df$Group,sep=".")

g = ggplot(df, aes(x = wave, y = outcome, color = grp, shape = grp))+
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = outcome - ci, ymax = outcome + ci), width = .25, position = pd, size=.5) +
geom_point(position = pd, size = 3.5, fill = "white", stroke = 1.25) +
scale_color_manual(values = c("#000000", "#000000","#606060", "#606060")) +
scale_shape_manual(values = c(23,21,23,21)) +
coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1.4, 1.6), ylim = c(-.91, .91)) +
labs(title = "Outcomes by Population and Study Group", x = "Time", y = "Outcome\nLower scores denote fewer instances") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black"), 
axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black"), panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#F0F0F0"))

print(g)
```

[image]

Then add the line while specifying the legend:

```
g + 
geom_line(inherit.aes=FALSE,aes(x = wave, y = outcome,group=grp,linetype=grp)) +
scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid","dashed","solid","dashed"))
```

[image]